# Facing an issue while configuring nginx. Getting empty pages while going to a specific path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Firstly I explain my issue here.
I have 3 react apps running on 4040 4141 4242 respectively.
Initially, I created 3 servers with three ports like

```
server {
listen 3000;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

   }
}

server {
listen 3001;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4141;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}
}
server {
listen 3002;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4242;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

}
}
```

This was working fine. But I need to serve all these three apps from one port.
eg: http://localhost:8080/ab should redirect to port 4040 and
http://localhost:8080/ac should redirect to port 4141 like so.

Now I tried this way

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name localhost;

location /examcontrol {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
}
location /student {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4141;
}
location  /staff {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4242;
}
}
```

This will redirect to the port 4040,4141,4242
but only some tags are visible like `<title>,<script>,<noscript>` etc no other contents is shown in the browser. (if I change `/examcontrol` to `/` I get the correct response and redirected to 4040, but no idea why these paths not working :( )
Please help if anyone knows this to configure it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could fix this easily by changing your `proxy_pass` directive (note the trailing `/`):

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:4242/;
```

Comment: I tried this way also same issue still there. In location block if i remove /examcontrol to /
is working fine. I think issue is the with the location do you have any idea ?